# regex for diagnosis

Tags: r, regex, option-type

a propper diagnosis in my data can have the format:

```
"F10"
"F10.1"
"F32.124"
```

I try to extract these correct format within a for loop:

```
Diagnosen[i] <- str_extract(Diagnosen[i], pattern = "F[:digit:]{2}[\\.[:digit:]{1,3}]?")
```

But the results are cut off after the point. Exp:

```
"F10."
```

what is not a correct format and lost information.

My pattern shall mean: Find the string beginning with an F and 2 digits. Optional is a point with one to three digits.

Please help me.
Best Sebastian

Comment: Replace bracket expression with a grouping construct, `"F[:digit:]{2}(\\.[:digit:]{1,3})?"`

Comment: you can try `grep("^F\\d{2}(\\.\\d{1,3})?$", diagnosen, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Wiktors solution worked for me. I didn't have to change the rest of my thinking, what was quite good for me. Thank you, Cath aswell.